# Java: tokens in memory and garbage collection

Tags: java, token

I was thinking today about whether this piece of code is secure:

```
String token = <<**token received from REST API call**>>

String encryptedToken = Base64.encodeToString(token.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT))
```

You are saving the token in memory and the actual token might still reside there until garbage collection.

Would this be more secure as we are not saving it inside a String hence we do not need to wait for garbage collection? We would just encrypt what we received back from the REST API directly.

```
String encryptedToken = Base64.encodeToString(<<**token received from REST API call**>>, Base64.DEFAULT))
```

Comment: Common practice is to pass around char[] references and zero them out when you're done. If your existing code passes strings around that might not work out so easily.

Comment: Garbage collection does not erase the bytes, it only adds them back to the pool of free memory. The bytes won't be erased until they are reallocated. So even forcing GC doesn't guarantee that memory is erased.

Comment: If you're worried about the first example, you should also be worried about the second, since it is not encrypted. It is simply encoded, which is trivial to decode.